# Heroku FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/images'

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I have a flask app which displays images from the ./static/images folder. This works perfectly when run on localhost using ngrok but when I deploy it to heroku, heroku is not able to access the files.

My project looks like this:
[Link to project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiEE4.png)

The '/' route functions is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route("/")
def hello_world():    
    files = os.listdir(os.path.join("static","images"))
    return render_template('index.html', files = files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then using Jinja2 templating I am showing the images using their filenames.

After deploying to heroku is shows the following error:

```
2022-06-04T14:09:05.109473+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/images'
2022-06-04T14:09:05.110195+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.88.68 - - [04/Jun/2022:14:09:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36"
2022-06-04T14:09:05.112279+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=tcs-flask-api.herokuapp.com request_id=f5749510-ffe0-461e-993c-f62b3984f698 fwd="223.190.83.232" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=502 protocol=https
```

I have tried using app.root_path but still got the same error. Only the path changes to app/static/images when using app.root_path.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
The error only comes up when the `static/images` folder is **empty**. I had to put a dummy image inside the folder and then using jinja2 template logic ignore that image while displaying. Can anyone help why that is the case

Comment: What is the _current directory_ in both environments?

Comment: How do we see the current directory?

Comment: `os.getcwd()` gives `Current Working Directory`

Comment: The current directory is `C:\Users\Aryan\Desktop\TCS files\Flask API` on my local device and `/app` for the heroku server